# I can see categories but product is not showing Magento2

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento2, amazon-rds

I have Magetique theme.
I have sample data comes with theme
I can see the categories but 
I can see any product

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question does not contain enough detail to provide any answers. For example, what application are you running (is it WordPress)? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks its Magento2.          Magetique theme only support magento2.